# pandas CSV to Parquet data type is not set correctly when column has no values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parquet, pyarrow

I'm using pandas data frame read_csv function, and from time to time columns have no values. In this case the data type sent using the **dtype** parameter is ignored.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", dtype={"col1": "str", "col2": "float", "col3": "str"})
df.to_parquet("example.parquet")
```

This is the CSV file I used:

```
col1,col2,col3
A,1,
B,2,
C,3,
```

I expect col3 to be of type in the parquet file, instead it is INT32

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to avoid error in case the columns has no values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", dtype={"col1": "str", "col2": "float", "col3": "str"}).fillna('')
df.to_parquet("example.parquet")
```

Comment: The values are actually null, though. Is there a dtype argument to `df.to_parquet`? If not, can you request one to be added?

Comment: the to_parquet doesn't have dtype args